# How to return and handle two different models in one view ?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0

I have this Controller to which I am passing a **User** object to a view which I based on **Stories** model from another view which is based on the **User** model. Fine. Now I am returning the **User** object to the view (the one based on **Stories** model) and want to use its properties there but since it's based on stories model so it expects **Stories** object and throws mismatch error.

How can I handle this? Like both.

Controller (To which User object has been passed)

```
 [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult GetImagesStories(Users u)
        {

            listofStories = bo.GetAllImages();
            ViewBag.Grid = listofStories;

            return View("GetImagesStories", u);
        }
```

The controller from which it is passed.

```
 [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Authenticate(Users u)
        {
            if (basicOps.getUsersLogin(u.UserName, u.Password)) 
            {
               u.UserID = 80909;
               return RedirectToAction("GetImagesStories", "Stories", u);

            }

            return View("Authenticate");


        }
```

The view to which the first controller is getting returned has this:

```
@model HimHer.Models.Stories
```

Comment: Use a view model containing properties for the models you need

Comment: You can use an interface or a common base class as your model

Answer (score 0):

Instead of parsing your `Users` to the view as a ViewModel, you should have a property `User(s)` on your `Stories` viewModel.

I typical name my models after usage:

Models used as parameters on incomming http calls like : UserRequestModel
Models used in views, like: UserViewModel
Models used on ajax/json return: UserResponseModel

So if my ViewModel needs data from my RequestModel, i pass those properties.